# Will a stop-limit-on-quote execute in extended trading?

Tags: united-states, stocks, trading, stock-markets, limit-order

As an example, if I have this order: `Buy 500 Shares of XYZ at Limit Price of $5.00 and Stop Price of $4.50. Duration of this order is Good until Cancelled.`

Will that order execute during extended trading hours, assuming the order was placed during regular market hours and the stop price is met and the limit price is accepted by a seller, or are these order types only applicable to regular trading hours?  I want to make sure before I place this order.

Comment: What country and stockexchange.

Comment: @Dheer USA on the NASDAQ

Comment: Should not the buy stop order be set at a price above the limit buy order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a quote from a call to the broker:

> Any orders placed during regular trading hours will only execute during regular trading hours. Extended trading is a special session, so you have to create an order during extended trading for it to execute, and any orders that are created during that session will expire when the session ends at 8pm. Additionally, you can only create regular limit orders during extended trading, so they do not have a stop-on-quote option.

Answer (score 4):

Your best option would be to check with your broker.

With some brokers you can select between what times of the day you want your order to be in the market. For example if you want to avoid the initial volatility in the first hour of trading, you can have a condition for your order to only be placed in the market between 11:00am to 4:00pm.